# My easeljs project doesn't work online

Tags: javascript, web, easeljs

I am developing a videogame using EaselJS, a Javascript library. 
My project works pretty fine offine, or on a local server. However, when I try to upload it on a website (ex: http://streetfighterjs.lixter.com/ ), it doesn't work anymore : my sprites aren't loading, and nothing is shown in my canvas. 
The strange thing is that I tried to use PreloadJS to preload my images, but it doesn't seems to work. I was wondering if anyone already had this kind of problem, and how did he made to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You only included `easel.js` and `sound.js`.

`preload.js` is missing. Therefore `createjs.LoadQueue` is `undefined`.

Just include `preload.js` and your code should work.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I did loaded PreloadJS, but my console seems to show an error because my character is undefined so is there a problem with my sprite ? Should I use preloadJS to create my Sprites too ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your console from time to time:

[image: typerror createjs is not a constructor]

Which is occuring from this line:

[image]

> Sounds like PreloadJS is not included, or not loaded. Can you provide
>   a link to the sample?

[Source](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/9183-error)

---

You are getting a typeffor from `perso1` which is undefined. I notice that you are creating your perso1 global variable, but you are not actually saying what perso1 is equal to. Well you might be later in the code, but when you are getting that typerror, perso1 is not yet set.

[image: perso1 undefined]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I loaded preloadJS but the problem seems to continue. I updaded my website if you want to check

Comment: I understand what might happen : my ticker loads faster than the spritesheet, so the ticker sends a mistake because my sprite isn't defined yet. I should preload my sprites too with my images, it should fix the problem. I'll let you know about it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include preloadjs in your head (or prefferably just after your footer element).

In my project right now, I have the following order and it works fine:

```
    <script src="../js/vendor/easeljs-0.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/soundjs-0.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/preloadjs-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the issue with the site is that `perso1` is undefined during your tick (deplacement function). This will happen as long as the first image (imgPerso1) is not loaded.

I am also seeing XMLHttpRequest errors in the console, indicating that something is attempting to load cross-domain. If your LoadQueue is causing this, then you might want to change it to load content using tag-based loading instead of XHR:

```
new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
```

A few miscellaneous notes:
1. You don't need to constantly call `stage.update()` when you make changes, because you have a ticker that will constantly update the stage for you.
2. You are still using the default timing mode for Ticker (timeout-based). There is no `useRAF` property in version 0.8.1 - instead set the `timingMode` of the Ticker:

```
createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
```

Hope that helps.